# Black textures on Unity android when building development build with script debugging

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, build-settings

When building an android apk with both "development build" and "script debugging" checked in the build settings, all my textures appear black, even the Unity splash screen is not present (likely black).
I'm using Unity 5.0.1f1 and I'm building an android apk (API 19, KitKat)
I've tried other API levels, the results are the same.

Create a new project, new scene and add a single UI button using GameObject->UI->Button.
Open up the Build Settings and add the scene. Select Android.

If I build&run with either the "development build" or "script debugging" option unchecked, the splash screen and button will display correctly.

If I build&run with both the "development build" and "script debugging" options checked, the splash screen and button will be black.

I'm using a Nexus 5 as the target, unfortunately I don't have any other devices I can test with.

If I remove the texture from the button by clearing the "Source Image" field in the Image script, the button will no longer be black and will display correctly (but now there's no texture)

The above is the simplest repro case. The original issue was that all textures are completely black in my game when building "development build" and "script debugging" options checked. The alpha channel of the tint is still respected, so the black textures can be semi-transparent.

If I build a standalone PC with "development build" and "script debugging" checked then the button will display correctly.

Does anyone else get this issue?
Anyone know what might be different about a "development build" and "script debugging" for android that could cause black textures?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the Log file provide any useful information at all?

Comment: Try it in an emulator (Genymotion, etc) yet? Link up a .apk and I'll give it a shot on a couple devices here.